# PHP query for mysql data getting name from id

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Having some problems geting the name from previos table.
first table has id and name.

### Table 1

ID  |  NAME

The second table from wich i get results has the id from first table

### Table 2

ID  | TABLE1_ID

How do i run query where ID from Table 2 is used to find the name in Table 1?

Comment: no idea what your asking us

Comment: Okay, better job editing your question.  Does my answer not provide the results?  Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT ft.name FROM firsttable ft INNER JOIN secondtable st ON st.firsttable_id=ft.id WHERE st.id=123'

I assume you have two tables, and you are referring to the "previous" table as the one of the tables, right?

The whole point of SQL is really joining tables based on some primary key and another foreign key in the other table.

The way you do so (at least the way I like to do so) is using the 'JOIN' keyword.

Table 1:  ID=5, NAME="bla"
Table 2:  ID=6, TABLE1_ID=5

Given table2_id=6, joins table2.TABLE1_ID=5 with table1.id=5, so returns NAME of bla

Please update your question if I am not answering it correctly.

Comment: You've got my vote but could you explain a little better what is happening there for the OP?